# ie getelementsbyID with same ID

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

i have a script that works with internet explorder (ie) and i need to loop the select fields, that it zelf is no ploblem bu the 4 elements got the same ID (on the same page).

How do i let it loop through the 4 fields?
Can i make them more spesified?

the code i use is the following:

```
ie.document.getElementByID("DownloadImage").Click
```

The ie code is the following:
field 1

```
<a id="DownloadButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$ctl00$declaratiebestandView$RetourInformatieGrid$ctl03$DownloadButton','')">CZ_Specificatie_150005697.pdf</a>
```

field 2

```
<a id="DownloadButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$ctl00$declaratiebestandView$RetourInformatieGrid$ctl03$DownloadButton','')">CZ_Specificatie_150005697.pdf</a><input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$ctl00$declaratiebestandView$RetourInformatieGrid$ctl03$DownloadImage" class="inlineButton" id="DownloadImage" type="image" src="../images/download.png" text="CZ_Specificatie_150005697.pdf">
```

then it opens the download screen, and then my code continue's (and works :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop them by using querySelectorAll to gather all the elements with an id attribute whose values match what you are after. You can distinguish between them by index. This method will allow you to gather them even though the ids are repeating. However, the HTML you have shared downloads the same document so a loop doesn't seem necessary.

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long
Set nodeList = ie.document.querySelectorAll("[id=DownloadButton]")
For i = 0 to nodeList.Length-1
    nodeList.item(i).Click
Next
```

That loops all of the matching elements and clicks

By index will be specific but if you familiarize yourself with CSS selectors there are a vast number of possibilities for specifying an element.

Comment: i use this variant of the code but is works the first time but not the seccont time. i tested uit by replaysing the "for 0" to "for 1" and then it does work,... but is does not work in a loop. (afther first i reload the first page)

Comment: _**Set Decl_list_0 = ie.document.querySelectorAll("[id=btnSelectDeclaratie]")
For q = 0 To Decl_list_0.Length - 1
    YN = 0
    Decl_list_0.Item(q).Click**_

Comment: Can you formulate this as an [mcve] and ask as a question please?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: i dont know how i get the question ask in the right way. do you want me to open a new topic? then i have more options.

Comment: You should ask as a new question because trying to debug here in comments is not effective. You can practice drafting the question using the question wizard I think. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard

Answer (score 2):

The `id` in HTLM must be unique. If it is not unique it is no valid HTML and should be fixed.

HTML4:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html

Section 7.5.2:

> id = name [CS]
>       This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

HTML5:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.

Comment: yes that is exactly what I expected. unfortunately there is nothing in the fields to see what makes it uniqe in the fields. I was thinking of looking for a name myself but unfortunately that does not result in the click action. then website is unfortunately not mine, so i cant fix it :(